# Generating various versions of Boost UUID (Universally Unique ID)

Tags: c++, boost, uuid, distributed, distributed-computing

I was reading up about Boost UUID. I understand that there are various ways of generating UUIDs, this is determined by the version field of the UUID. [This document](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) shows 5 different versions of UUID. The Boost UUID API let you query a UUID for it's version. But how does one set the version? The [Boost documentation page](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjTsYCs0a_LAhVC9R4KHan-BSwQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boost.org%2Fdoc%2Flibs%2F1_60_0%2Flibs%2Fuuid%2Fuuid.html&usg=AFQjCNEGzfGZ_Vb0WrN54yVbeu-cnX3RWA&bvm=bv.116274245,d.dmo) shows only one way of creating a UUID, as follows -

```
boost::uuids::uuid u = boost::uuids::random_generator()();
```

So, can you please show me how to generate UUIDs based on the other 4 versions? Especially version 1, i.e. time-based generator seems very interesting to me.

Also, can you please tell me how is a UUID version different from it's variant? They both sound like the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the Uuid library from Boost before, but I perused the code a bit and it appears as though the `version` and `variant` of the `uuid` is based on the `generator` you use.

There are multiple kinds of generators, for example, [`random_generator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#boost/uuid/name_generator.hpp) and [`name_generator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#boost/uuid/name_generator.hpp). Each generator will have it's own values of `version` and `variant` it will inject into the resultant `uuid`.

This is straight from the source code, note how the variants and versions are different for the two generators.

## random_generator.hpp

```
// set variant
// must be 0b10xxxxxx
*(u.begin()+8) &= 0xBF;
*(u.begin()+8) |= 0x80;

// set version
// must be 0b0100xxxx
*(u.begin()+6) &= 0x4F; //0b01001111
*(u.begin()+6) |= 0x40; //0b01000000
```

## name_generator.hpp

```
// set variant
// must be 0b10xxxxxx
*(u.begin()+8) &= 0xBF;
*(u.begin()+8) |= 0x80;

// set version
// must be 0b0101xxxx
*(u.begin()+6) &= 0x5F; //0b01011111
*(u.begin()+6) |= 0x50; //0b01010000
```

Comment: The time-based generator, i.e. version 1 seems the most interesting to me. Can you offer any suggestions where I could find how it can be used to generate the UUID? I don't see it in the doc.

Comment: Just perusing the code at the four generators, it doesn't appear, at first glance anyways, that there is a generator that generates a "version 1" UUID.

Comment: @First, You might want to check into **Mahonri Moriancumer's
UUID and GUID Generator and Forensics** [link](http://www.mahonri.info/cgi/uuid.cgi) to get a better idea of how each version of the RFC 4122 variation are structured.